# mysql_upgrade - Can't create database 'performance_schema'

Tags: mysql

I run out of space on my VPS where I host many production sites.
I discovered there is a 2GB+ file in `/var/log/mysqld.log`

This file constains similar lines:

```
2019-11-01T12:21:57.708857Z 30600 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-11-01T12:21:57.709106Z 30600 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-11-01T12:21:57.709135Z 30600 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-11-01T12:21:57.709380Z 30600 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-11-01T12:21:57.709399Z 30600 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
```

I made a `mysqldump` backup.
I tried to run `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` but it fails:

```
     ~]# mysql_upgrade -u root -p
Enter password:
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1006: Can't create database 'performance_schema' (errno: 15749056)
```

Please suggest what's wrong. I made a reasearch in stackoverflow as well as on google, but I coulnd't find anything that could help me resolve this problem.
Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Here is the version I have:

```
Server version: 5.7.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Running on Centos 7.

Update: I also tried (as suggested below):

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

But in the folder /usr/local/ there are no mysql related folders.

Then I tried `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`
the command was fine. But the problem still persists.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/data
```

If it doesn't resolves, you may try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719748/error-1006-hy000-cant-create-database-errno-13-mysql-5-6-12#18720928)
Hope this helps.

Comment: tried. It didn't work. I updated the original question.